# How to use wordpress with any "site url" (the url in settings) for development?

Tags: plugins

For development I want to be able to use my wordpress site with localhost, and with a variety of IPs, maybe even with some throwaways domain names.

Now wordpress doesn't allow, you have to choose 1 "site url" and change it every time you decide to use a different port or different test server IP.

I am aware I can change hosts file on my local computer, but that doesn't work if I am hosting a site temporarily for a client to test. I don't want to have to get them to change their hosts file.

How can I modify wordpress to make this work? Is there a plugin that does such a thing? If not, how can I make my own plugin or hack wordpress to make it do what I want? I am a developer but I don't know wordpress, php and apache very well.

Could it be as simple as making a plugin that overrides global vars like `site_url` and what not?

Example the wp site should load and not redirect if I visit:

`http://localhost` (assuming I'm listening on port 80)

`http://localhost:3000` (assuming I'm listening on port 3000)

`http://wordpress-test` (assuming I change my hosts file)

`http://123.123.123.123` (assuming the site is listening on that server at port 80)

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit more than just the option to update unfortunately.  I'd recommend reading over https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/ to learn about what is involved first.  As far as plugin solutions, there's lots that exist already, which would be a safer route than rolling your own. [Better Search and Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) is a popular one.

Since you're going to be doing this url change for client previews vs local dev vs production - I'd assume you either already have wp-cli or can easily get it up and running.  It already has a built in search and replace you can do:

```
wp search-replace http://local.test https://throwaway-domain.com/subdirectory --skip-columns=guid --dry-run
```

From [wp-cli documentation for search-replace](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/), this script is useful as well:

```
# Bash script: Search/replace production to development url (multisite compatible)
#!/bin/bash
if $(wp --url=http://example.com core is-installed --network); then
    wp search-replace --url=http://example.com 'http://example.com' 'http://example.test' --recurse-objects --network --skip-columns=guid --skip-tables=wp_users
else
    wp search-replace 'http://example.com' 'http://example.test' --recurse-objects --skip-columns=guid --skip-tables=wp_users
fi
```

**Note**: *You might have noticed the flag `--skip-columns=guid` in both examples, which is explained in the first link under [Important GUID Note](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/#important-guid-note).  Similarly the **Better Search and Replace** plugin mentioned has a checkbox to skip Replacing GUIDs.*

As you mentioned you use docker in another comment, you can take a look at this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50999848/how-to-run-wp-cli-in-docker-compose-yml).

Comment: im not looking for a solution to quickly search and replace, I'm looking for a solution that lets me use any url to access an ip address:port that resolves to the wordpress site

Answer (score 0):

You can try theese hook filters

```
add_filter('home_url', 'my_url', 10, 2);
add_filter('site_url', 'my_url', 10, 2);

function my_url($url, $path) {
   return 'http://your-dev-hostname-or-ip-here/' . $path;
}
```

However keep in mind, that original (real) site url will still be used in many places in content. To fix that you can use additional hook on `the_content` and do string replacement there.

Comment: thanks that looks like it might work if I replace the url string with `$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']` or something like that. My goal is to dynamically allow any site url to be used.

Answer (score -1):

Wordpress is PHP based and requires a database server such as MySQL or MariaDB.

I would suggest using a development environment such as LAMP, WAMP or similar. The software is free and will install a development environment including Apache, PHP, MySQL and sometimes Phpmyadmin.

You will get Apache, PHP, MySQL and a control panel for setting up test domains stored locally on your PC.

You wont really need to be an expert in any of the packages installed as you will have a control panel for setting up databases (needed by Wordpress) and for creating test domains.

I am assuming you are using a Windows operating system, in which case you want it's an easy process. The [AMP](https://ampps.com/) style packages are available for both Windows and Linux.

Setting up a good test environment will give you good experience and it is an excellent way to learn because you can't hurt anyone but yourself if you make a mistake.

There are thousands of pages on the net with help using all the packages included in the AMP distributions.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: How does LAMP/WAMP solve the multiple domain problem? I already use docker for my dev and production environment and not looking to change it.

Comment: I don't use either anymore but from what I recall you could set up any number of domains and subdomains. I have probably misunderstood your question. I would have left a comment but have of a lack of rep (I'm new here). Sadly I've been down voted :(

Comment: I see you've edited the question which makes it clearer what you are trying to do. My answer is related more to subdomains and domains running locally and include a PHP processor needed for Wordpress.